# How to make hitting delete key delete file on not-Ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning, nautilus, delete, trash

Ubuntu automatically recognizes and mounts my Windows partition, where I store many of my files. However, when opening a folder on this partition in Nautilus, nothing happens, while doing so on the Ubuntu partition moves the files to the bin.

I would expect the 'permanently delete?' warning (as I do get when doing 'right click - delete').

Is there a way to change this? (also if it's normal behaviour) If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this is the normal behaviour , to permanently delete any file you should click shift+delete together

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured as well. I've changed my original question a bit, as I'd like to change this behaviour.